# What is the difference between <Box> and <View> in Native Base?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

As the title says. In what scenario would you use a Box instead of a View

Answer (score 0):

Box and View basically is a same thing. Both implements React Native's View and plus native base [utility props](https://docs.nativebase.io/utility-props) enabled.

The only different I know so far I notice is the Box has [safearea props](https://docs.nativebase.io/safe-area-view-props) support, which View don't have.

You can check their props implementation [Box](https://docs.nativebase.io/box#h2-props) and [View](https://docs.nativebase.io/view#h2-props)

Thus, use whichever as your prefer. When you need safearea support out of the box then you should use Box instead.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @EdwingWong's answer, another difference is that you can apply [gradient](https://docs.nativebase.io/box#h3-with-linear-gradient) for Box component if you are using [expo-linear-gradient](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/) or [react-native-linear-gradient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient), but it doesn't seem to work using View.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, Box, View } from 'native-base'

const Example = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Box
        bg={{
          linearGradient: {
            colors: ['green.100', 'green.900'],
          }
        }}
      >
        <Text color='red.600'>Box component</Text>
      </Box>

      <View
        bg={{
          linearGradient: {
            colors: ['green.100', 'green.900'],
          }
        }}
      >
        <Text color='red.600'>View component</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  )
}

export default Example
```

[image]